# Does using regular expressions in a SQL Select statement change real data?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g

```
select orderid from orders where REGEXP_REPLACE(orderid,'/^0+(.)/')
```

I have searched the documentation and am missing it.  If I run this query will it change any real data or just my set returned for output (the "virtual" data)?  The word replace scares me.  I am using oracle 11g.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are performing a `SELECT`, you end up getting a read only view of the data, nothing has changed.

So you don't need to worry about running this select statement.  The only way to update it would be to follow this up with an `UPDATE` command.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. *(even though this answer is too short for SO).*